# Import list of list to a file in a tabulated array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a list of lists in python, like this

`list = [['A','mouse', 5],['A','lion', 7], ['B','mouse', 3],['B','lion', 4]]`

What I want to do is to print this list to a tabulated file with the next structure:

```
       A    B
mouse  5    3
lion   7    4
```

I tried using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

but I can't get the table, even import it into a file
how can I do this?

Comment: it is basic long to wide problem :) you can search by the key words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add pivot after `df = pd.DataFrame(list)`

```
df.pivot(index=1,columns=0,values=2)
Out[920]: 
0      A  B
1          
lion   7  4
mouse  5  3
```

As Per MaxU

```
pd.DataFrame(ll).pivot(index=1,columns=0,values=2).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
Out[925]: 
       A  B
lion   7  4
mouse  5  3
```

Comment: Maybe: `pd.DataFrame(lst).pivot(index=1,columns=0,values=2).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)`?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
list = [['A','mouse', 5],['A','lion', 7], ['B','mouse', 3],['B','lion', 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list)


df.set_index([1,0])[2].unstack().rename_axis(None)
```

Output:

```
       A  B
lion   7  4
mouse  5  3
```

Comment: Very nice solution! ++ :)

Comment: @MaxU  Thanks :-)